# Integrating $\int\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}dx$ via trig substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

What I have done so far:
Substituting $$x=3\sin(t)\Rightarrow dx=3\cos(t)dt$$ converting our integral to 
$$I=\int\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}dx=\int \frac{27\sin^3(t) dt}{3\sqrt{\cos^2(t)}}3\cos(t)dt\\
\Rightarrow \frac{I}{27}=\int \sin^3(t)dt=-\frac{\sin^2(t)\cos(t)}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\int\sin(t)dt\\
\Rightarrow I=18\cos(t)-9\sin^2(t)\cos(t)+c$$
Which is where I'm stuck. I can substitute back in for the $\sin(t)$ terms but don't know hot to deal with the $\cos(t)$ terms and back out information about $x$.

edited: because I miswrote the problem, I am sorry.

Comment: Not an answer, but our function is $\frac{-x(9-x^2)+9x}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}$, that is, $\frac{9x}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}-x\sqrt{9-x^2}$, and now we can let $u=9-x^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nice trick to do in this situation is to write

$$
\sin^3t = (1-\cos^2t)\sin t.
$$

You can now do a secondary $u$-substitution where you can take $u = \cos t$ and $du = -\sin tdt$.

**Edit**

Where you left off you had

$$
\frac{I}{27} \;\; =\;\; \int \sin^3t dt \;\; =\;\; \int (1-\cos^2t)\sin t dt
$$

If we now take the $u$-substitution I suggested above we find

$$
\frac{I}{27} \;\; =\;\;- \int (1 - u^2) du \;\; =\;\; \frac{1}{3}u^3 - u + C
$$

for some constant $C$.  We can do the first re-substitution

$$
\frac{I}{27} \;\; =\;\; \frac{1}{3} \cos^3t - \cos t+C
$$

and now you can do the other substitution by noting that $\cos t = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2t} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{9}} = \frac{1}{3} \sqrt{9 - x^2}$.

**Additional Edit**

If we plug back in the above expressions we get

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{I}{27} & = & \cos t\left (\frac{1}{3}\cos^2t - 1\right ) + C \\
& = & \frac{1}{3} \sqrt{9-x^2}\left (\frac{1}{27}(9-x^2) - 1\right ) + C\\
I & = & \frac{1}{3} \sqrt{9-x^2} (9- x^2 - 27) + C \\
& = & -\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{9-x^2}(x^2 + 18) + C.
\end{eqnarray*}

The answer you saw on Wolfram Alpha was the result of taking through the calculation as far as it could go.

Comment: @qbert I just edited my answer.  See if this makes it clearer now.

Comment: this helps a lot thank you! Also I think you dropped and picked back up a $u$ term in there

Comment: @qbert The answer on Wolfram Alpha is the result of continuing on with the method I suggested above.  Please see some additional edits I made above.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Think of *Pythagoras' identity* (which you used  to remove the square root).

Your substitution was not done rigourously: it has to correspond to a bijective substitution. You should have set $t=\arcsin\dfrac x3$, i.e. $-\frac\pi2\le t\le\frac\pi2$.

Comment: Oh I never thought about bijectivity but I'm sorry, I don't understand the last part about the substitution; how does setting $t=\arcsin(x/3)$ and restricting $x$ to some interval solve things? Is the idea that I am solving the integral for a bunch of different intervals?

Comment: By Pythagoras, you have $\cos^2t$, i.e; you have $\lvert\cos t\rvert$.

Comment: ah sorry I see now how to solve it, but still don't understand the bijective transformation portion. Am I technically only solving this integral for a bunch of intervals?

Comment: If you want to go back from $t$ to $x$ you need a bijection. Otherwise you can't go back.

Answer (score 0):

Substitution $x=3\sin{y} \rightarrow dx=3\cos{y}$ $dy$

Then

$27 \int \frac{\sin^3{y}}{3\cos{y}}.3\cos{y}$ $dy$

$=\frac{27}{4}\int 4\sin^3{y}$ $dy$

Use Identity

$4\sin^3{y}=3\sin{y}-\sin{3y}$

$\frac{27}{4}\int 4\sin^3{y}$ $dy$ $=\frac{27}{4}\int 3\sin{y}-\sin{3y}$ $dy$

$=\frac{27}{4}(-3\cos{y}-\frac{\cos{3y}}{3})$

From substitution,

$\cos{y}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}$

$\cos{3y}=4\cos^3{y}-3\cos{y}$

$\therefore \frac{27}{4}(-3\cos{y}-\frac{\cos{3y}}{3})=\frac{27}{4}[-\frac{9}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}-\frac{1}{3}(\frac{108}{(9-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}-\frac{9}{\sqrt{9-x^2}})]$

You should be able to carry forward.Good luck!