# Choosing integration strategy

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to integrate this function:

$$\int \frac {x^3}{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \;dx$$

I don't know how i should integrate,  should i divide because the numerator has an higher grade?
There is any strategy i should know for choosing the best way?

Comment: A [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826494/integrating-int-fracx3-sqrt9-x2dx-via-trig-substitution/1826499#1826499) similar to this one was answered recently.

Comment: Whenever you see $x^2$ in the square root, become suspicious of using a trigonometric substitution.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{1)}$ Let $u=4-x^2, du=-2x dx$ to get

$\hspace{.2 in}\displaystyle\int\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx=-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}(-2x) dx=-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{4-u}{\sqrt{u}}du=-\frac{1}{2}\int\left(4u^{-1/2}-u^{1/2}\right)du$

$\hspace{.2 in}\displaystyle=-\frac{1}{2}\left(8u^{1/2}-\frac{2}{3}u^{3/2}\right)+C=-4(4-x^2)^{1/2}+\frac{1}{3}(4-x^2)^{3/2}+C$

---

$\textbf{2)}$ Let $\displaystyle u=x^2, dv=\frac{x}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx,\;\;$ so $du=2x dx$ and $v=-(4-x^2)^{1/2}$.

Then $\displaystyle\int\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx=-x^2(4-x^2)^{1/2}-\int-2x(4-x^2)^{1/2}dx=-x^2(4-x^2)^{1/2}-\frac{2}{3}(4-x^2)^{3/2}+
C$

---

$\textbf{3)}$ Let $x=2\sin t, dx=2\cos t dt$ to get

$\hspace{.2 in}\displaystyle\int\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx=\int\frac{(2\sin t)^3}{2\cos t}\cdot 2\cos t dt=8\int\sin^3 t \,dt=8\int(1-\cos^2 t)\sin t dt$

$\hspace{.2 in}\displaystyle =-8\int(1-u^2)du=-8\left(u-\frac{u^3}{3}\right)+C=-8\left(\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{2}\right)^3\right)+C$

$\hspace{.2 in}\displaystyle=-4\sqrt{4-x^2}+\frac{1}{3}(4-x^2)^{3/2}+C$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One may first make the change of variable $u=x^2$, $du=2x\,dx$, giving
$$
\int \frac {x^3dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}=\frac12\int \frac {u\:du}{\sqrt{4-u}}
$$ then $v=\sqrt{4-u}$, $u=v^2+4$, $du=2v\,dv$, thus
$$
\int \frac {x^3dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}=\int (v^2+4)\:dv
$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int  \frac { x^{ 3 } }{ \sqrt { 4-x^{ 2 } }  } dx=\int { \frac { { x }^{ 2 }x }{ \sqrt { 4-x^{ 2 } }  }  } dx=-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int { \frac { \left( 4-{ x }^{ 2 }-4 \right)  }{ \sqrt { 4-{ x }^{ 2 } }  } d{ x }^{ 2 } } =$$ $$-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int { \sqrt { 4-{ x }^{ 2 } } d{ x }^{ 2 } } +2\int { \frac { d{ x }^{ 2 } }{ \sqrt { 4-{ x }^{ 2 } }  }  } =$$ $$\\ =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int { \sqrt { 4-{ x }^{ 2 } }  } d\left( 4-{ x }^{ 2 } \right) -2\int { \frac { d\left( 4-{ x }^{ 2 } \right)  }{ \sqrt { 4-{ x }^{ 2 } }  }  } =\frac { 1 }{ 3 } { \left( 4-{ x }^{ 2 } \right)  }^{ \frac { 3 }{ 2 }  }-4{ \left( 4-{ x }^{ 2 } \right)  }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  }+C$$