# Evaluate the definite integral using trig. sub $\int\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, substitution

The integral is 
$$\int\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}dx$$
I see that if we remove the numerator I can get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}$ which is the derivative of arcsin but I can't get rid of the numerator, so instead I used $$u=\sqrt{9-x^2}$$
$$du=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}$$
$$u^2=9-x^2 \to u^2-9=-x^2$$
Continuing with this substitution method 
$$\int\frac{x^3}{u}\left(-\frac{u}{x}\right)du$$
$$\int-x^2dx \to \int(u^2-9)du=\frac{1}{3}u^3-9u+C$$
Even though this is the correct answer, I am wondering of a way to solve it that implements $\arcsin(x)$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri yep you're right, I fixed it.

Comment: Have you tried $x=3\sin\theta$?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri So the way I solved it is the only U-Sub method?

Comment: Read the updated comment. Another substitution could be $x^2=t$, which solves it without trigonometry.

Comment: Why not using straightforward integration by parts?  Start with $$-\frac12\int x^2\frac{-2x}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}\,dx=-\frac12\int x^2\bigl(2\sqrt{9-x^2}\bigr)'\,dx.$$

Comment: AFAICT in your post you're asking about *indefinite integral* rather a *definite integral*.

Comment: Here is an older post about the same integral: [Integrating $\int\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}dx$ via trig substitution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1826494). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E3%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B9-x%5E2%7D%7Ddx%24&p=1). See also: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Comment: @EricBrown Just to explain about the arcsine. In your specific example, the $\arcsin$ function vanishes. You can think of it as the coefficient in front of the $\arcsin$ being $0$. If you change the numerator to $x^2$ for instance, the answer will involve an $\arcsin$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Set $\; x=3\sin t,\enspace -\frac \pi 2<x<\frac\pi 2$, $\;\mathrm dx=3\cos t\,\mathrm d t$, to obtain
$$\int\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx=\int\frac{3^3\sin^3t}{\sqrt{9(1-\sin^2t)}}\,3\cos t\,\mathrm dt=27\int\sin^3 t\,\mathrm d t=-27\int(1-\cos^2t)\, \mathrm d(\cos t).$$